# android Accessibility focusSearch does not return any node

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

My Accessibility service would go through the focusable nodes. I am trying to use the [focusSearch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#focusSearch(int)) function for this, but that is not giving any node back. But the layout contains focusable items. Here is the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Hello World2" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Button2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

So what I tried is to find the first button:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo root = getRootInActiveWindow();
AccessibilityNodeInfo node1 = null;
node1 = root.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("my.app:id/button1").get(0);
//returns button view
node1 = root.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN); //returns null
node1 = root.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_LEFT); //returns null
node1 = root.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT); //returns null
node1 = root.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD); //returns null
```

However using [findFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#findFocus(int)) it gives back the framelayout

```
node1 = root.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_ACCESSIBILITY);
//returns node of the main framelayout
```

Then I used this node for next search, but nothing found again.

```
node1 = node1.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD); //returns null
```

And when I call `findfocus` instead of `focusSearch` i got the same node back

```
node1 = node1.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_ACCESSIBILITY);
//returns the same node
```

So the question is how can I go through on the focusable nodes within a layout?

Comment: There is no API version mentioned.  Can we assume you intend to support the most up to date APIs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misconception.  What you are searching for is objects that can take input focus (think EditText controls). This is fundamentally different from Accessibility Focus.  There are no input focusable controls in your layout.

The functions you want are:

```
someAccessibilityNodeInfo.getTraversalAfter();
```

and

```
someAccessibilityNodeInfo.getTraversalBefore();
```

There is no up/down equivalent.  Though you could calculate this however you want.  You could store the entire heirarchy of accessibility focusable nodes in an array, and calculate up/down based on x and y positions.

Comment: trying it I will come back with the result..i used API 19, but I switch to 22 temporarily

Comment: The traversal function just does a Tree Traversal of nodes that you'd expect to interract with.  Re-implementing the logic should be fairly trivial.

Comment: I just can not switch to api 22 - but I implemented the traversal you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Exactly! The view containers are returned because they are present in the tree.

What you need is the leaf nodes.

This code will give you a list of nodes(leaf nodes) that are focusable:

```
ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> inputViewsList = new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
refreshChildViewsList(rootNode);
for(AccessibilityNodeInfo mNode : inputViewsList){
    if(mNode.isFocusable()){
        //do whatever you want with the node...
    }
}
```

`refreshChildViewsList` method:

```
private void refreshChildViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode){
    int childCount = rootNode.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0; i<childCount ; i++){
        AccessibilityNodeInfo tmpNode = rootNode.getChildAt(i);
        int subChildCount = tmpNode.getChildCount();
        if(subChildCount==0){
            inputViewsList.add(tmpNode);
            return; 
        } else {
            refreshChildViews(tmpNode);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Let me know if there's any issue with this code!

Comment: yes, I already implemented similar things - but thanks anyway